# Can't seem to install Spectacle from NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, plotly, spectacle

I'm not a Software Eng so not very familiar with Node.js and NPM, I'm trying to install Spectacle to test it out with Plotly charts but I'm stuck in the first step to get it installed through npm. I'm following [this step by step guide](https://github.com/sourcey/spectacle) but can't seem to make it work. Below is the error I'm receiving, can someone help me figure out what's needed to do in order to finish the installation successfully?

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.3.5: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated superagent@7.1.6: Please downgrade to v7.1.5 if you need IE/ActiveXObject support OR upgrade to v8.0.0 as we no longer support IE and published an incorrect patch version (see https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/1731)
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.7.1: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated highlight.js@9.18.5: Support has ended for 9.x series. Upgrade to @latest
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\spectacle-docs',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\then-request'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\spectacle-docs\\node_modules\\then-request'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\spectacle-docs\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\tools\gyp\pylib'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\spectacle-docs\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\tools\\gyp\\pylib'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\spectacle-docs',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\foundation-sites'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\spectacle-docs\\node_modules\\foundation-sites'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\spectacle-docs\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\js-beautify\js\test\resources'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\spectacle-docs\\node_modules\\js-beautify\\js\\test\\resources'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\spectacle-docs\\node_modules\\js-beautify',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\js-beautify\js\test\resources'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\spectacle-docs\\node_modules\\js-beautify\\js\\test\\resources'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\spectacle-docs\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:306:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\spectacle-docs\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\stalebian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\spectacle-docs\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

I read on some other Stackoverflow discussions to un-install the npm and install it back but that didn't work either.

Comment: The permission on the `C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm` folder probably are messed up somehow. Try a command prompt launched in admin mode (Right click on Command Prompt and click "Run as administrator") and see if that works?

Comment: Gave it a try and still got the same error.....

Comment: Hmm. At this point I'd try manually deleting the `C:\\Users\\stalebian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules` folder (its just a cache).

Comment: Hello, are you still struggling with the installation?

Comment: ended up finding the .exe file and installing it that way. Through cmd it was impossible to install it, kept getting all kinds of errors